# update variable every 1 second

Tags: java

hi i am new in java programming i have a big problem when i use timer or while loop for my program to show my variable and update it my program will stopped,  not stopped working just nothing i cant do anything in my program my game is a easy game that we should got money from ... ways and i want to show my money every x second. every second isn't important for me just a code that not stop my program, here is my money code:

```
       static int money = 0;
       static int energy = 100;
       static String energyinfo = Integer.toString(energy);
       static String moneyinfo = Integer.toString(money);

       private void setmoneyenergy()
       {
            energyinfo = Integer.toString(energy);
            moneyinfo = Integer.toString(money);
            jenergy.setText(energyinfo);
            jmoney.setText(moneyinfo);
       }
```

while is in a button actionperformed

```
    while(true)
    {
       setpoolenergy();
    }
```

Comment: Do not block on the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).